# Serving static files from grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin, grails-controller, grails-2.4

I wrote a private plugin(**MyPlugin**) that is being used by other applications. It has a controller named **MyPluginController** and a bunch of REST actions. They all work fine when access through the mainapp. The plugin also comes with a single page app contained in **static.html**.  I could not figure out how to do the UrlMapping for **static.html** to be accessible like:
http://example.com/mainapp/MyPluginController/static.html

```java
class MyPluginUrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
"/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')

 /* Not sure what do here ???*/
 "/MyPluginController/static.html" (redirect: "/static.html", permanent: true)
}
```

The html is in myplugin's web-app folder. It is easy to rename it to .gsp and make it work but this is grails and I am sure there must be cleaner way of doing it.